# detect the key selected by user when clicked on ImageView

Tags: android, keyboard, key

I have an ImageView.I want when user clicks on it,android keyboard appears,user select a key and I catch the key selected and keyboard disappear.
I know how to show/hide the keyboard
but I wonder how to detect the key selected by the user.
Please don't tell me create my own keyboard.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Override onKeyDown():

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    //keyCode is the key that was pressed
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work for utf8 keyboards.in my case persian language alphabet :(